# RemoteApp opens and immediately closes

Tags: rds, remoteapp

We have a Windows Server 2012 R2 RDS server with everything configured fully, including licencing for RDS.  Best Practices Analyser passes in full.
On our Windows 8.1 Enterprise VMs which have some basic applications published as RemoteApps - Notepad, WordPad, and Calculator.  When these are called from RDWeb, a session appears to start - but immediately disconnects.
Our Windows 7 Enterprise VMs do NOT have the same problem.
What are we doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the event logs on the Remote Desktop Host server?

Comment: Yes, nothing of interest there.  Just this:
Remote Desktop Virtualization Host successfully orchestrated the virtual machine named REMOTEAPP-2.

Virtual machine name: REMOTEAPP-2
Fully qualified domain name=REMOTEAPP-2.london.XXXXX.com
IP address=10.2.34.154

Comment: That looks like something from the host where you're running the VDI clients on, not the RemoteApp Session Host..

Comment: The same host runs RD Web Access, the RD Gateway, RD Licencing, the RD Connection Broker and RD Virtualization Host roles.  What do you mean by the RemoteApp Session Host?  The VM on which the RemoteApps actually reside?  I wouldn't even know how to check their event logs.

Comment: Could it have anything to do with the presence of a RemoteFx Video Adapter/vGPU on the RemoteApp VMs?

Comment: I unpublished the RemoteApps and logged in to the VMs.  All have this error: The RDVGM kernel mode driver failed to start. The VM will not run with RemoteFX. If this issue persists, consider running with a lower number of monitors, resolutions, VMs, or increasing the GPU capacity.

Comment: Yes, the server hosting the RemoteApp service..